# why my inner product in python's numpy is wrong?

Tags: python, numpy

i wrote two 1D complex vectors:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2+3j])
b = np.array([4+5j])
print(np.vdot(a, b))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

it retuned:

```
(23-2j)
```

instead of:

```
(-7+22j)
```

if a=2-3j i expect this result: (23-2j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy's [`vdot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vdot.html) takes the complex conjugate of the first argument. If you just use [`dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot) you'll get the answer you expect.